# How add custom method and fields to Liferay User model class

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to add 3 more methods and one field to `liferay.portal.model.User` class. Anyone knows how can I do this? Can I switch the class by hook like this:

```
<service>
    <service-type>com.liferay.portal.model.User</service-type>
    <service-impl>my.pack.userExpanded</service-impl>
</service>
```

I want to have a close look at service builder but can't find good sources which will show how to switch liferay class with my own class (cause of too many uses).

So second question is does anyone know about some good tutorial or blogs regarding this? Especially I am interested in adding extra methods and fields.

Answer (score 2):

The standard Liferay Developer Documentation is good:

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/overriding-a-portal-servi-4

Another alternative is to add `Custom Fields` to User entity:

Comment: I also need some methods so Custom Fields propably not a solution

Comment: You can create in a hook with the `Service Builder` a custom database table and DAO-Classes and develope a wrapper classes to access your custom tables.

Answer (score -2):

You can't modify a liferay entity. Neither you can use hook to modify these things, hook can only modify limited things as suggested by the [documentation](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/hoo-4).

I don't think you can even use a EXT to modify a liferay entity.

So now the what comes to my mind remains is to create `custom-fields` for your field requirement and build a helper utility class which will provide you with your required User methods.

You can make the helper class available to the portal by packaging in a jar and pasting it in the global path (in tomcat `[TOMCAT_HOME]/lib/ext`).

Comment: @downVoters Can you all please suggest why you are downvoting? Thanks